# Getting a request error on load

Tags: php, symfony, request

I recently jumped into Symfony and I'm following a (little outdated) symblog tutorial ([source](http://tutorial.symblog.co.uk/docs/validators-and-forms.html)), now in it, at one point he calls the request from a page:

```
public function indexAction() {
    $request = $this->getRequest();
    if ($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        //do stuff
    }

    return $this->render('BundleName:ClassController:view.html.twig');
    ));
}
```

Which I learned isn't supported any more, so I moved the controller as a parameter (as I understand, due to changes coming in Symfony3.0):

```
public function indexAction(Request $request) {
    if($request->getMethod() == 'POST') {
        //do stuff
    }
    return $this->render('BundleName:ClassController:view.html.twig');
}
```

but if I try to run this, I still get the following error:

> Controller "**BundleName\Controller\ClassController::indexAction()**" requires that you provide a value for the "*$request*" argument (because there is no default value or because there is a non optional argument after this one).

What's the issue here? Do I need to instantiate the `$request` object inside the controller action? Is there a configuration somewhere, where I'd need to implement the new implemented attribute?

Comment: I think Symfony controllers do type hint matching so this sounds like you need to include a `use` statement for `Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request`. If not then it might be something more pernicious.

Comment: @JohnNoel Yes, PHPStorm missed the implementation (implemented wrong type of Request), it works now.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Did you

```
use Symfony\Component\HttpFoundation\Request;
```

?

Comment: Oh, wow, I'm using PHPStorm and it autoimplemented Symfony\Component\BrowserKit\Request; instead, never saw it coming... Thank you! I'll approve as soon as I can.

Comment: Symfony namers did not help though... You don't know how many times I got wrong `Request` or `TokenStorageInterface` or ... ;)